# What's a good way to find out how much lead is in parts being used in toys?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, everyday-chemistry, analytical-chemistry, concentration

We are using parts from China in small-scale manufacturing of toys.  We used an abotec "lead inspector" test kit on the same part from 3 sources, using abotec's leach test, in which we soaked each part in white vinegar for more than 4 hours, and then added a few ml of the vinegar used to a drop of reagent on a swab.  The swab turned black each time, indicating that the part had at least 50 ppm of lead.  The vinegar in each test tube became a little cloudy, but none turned dark.  Any thoughts about how much lead, and whether that might be unsafe?  PBGC's standard is 100 ppm.

Comment: If that amateur kitchen test already finds lead, then you are most probably in hot water, but that's definitely not an adequate test. Find an analytical laboratory, get yourself a lawyer.